# Cypress: Some requests on website side get empty response

Tags: javascript, request, xmlhttprequest, response, cypress

We are currently trying to make test scripts for a webapp running in local.
However, some requests that are working on a basic browsers get an empty response on cypress test browser, which makes the tests fail.

I heard about a rule of Node that will return an empty response for any header that is more than 80kb, however, requests in my app never exceed 80kb, so I'm wondering what is going on.

Does anyone have a clue?

## Sent data

```
{
  id: -1
  project_id: 3605
  parent_id: 0
  title: Folder
  original_filename: Folder
  type: FOLDER
  created_datetime: 201905061228
  updated_datetime: 201905061228
  delete_flag: 0
  folder_type: 1
}
```

## Expected API response (what I get in a normal browser)

```
{
  "created_time":"2019-05-06 10:39:38",
  "updated_time":"2019-05-06 10:39:38",
  "purchase_datetime":null,
  "folder_type":"1",
  "id":9522,
  "project_id":"3605",
  "parent_id":"0",
  "title":"Folder 2",
  "original_filename":null,
  "type":"FOLDER",
  "original_xml":null,
  "updated_xml":null,
  "deleted_datetime":null,
  "delete_flag":"0",
  "status":null,
  "progress":null,
  "version_no":null,
  "purchase_flag":null
}
```

## What I get in Cypress browser (developer tools response tab)

```
This request has no response data available
```

Comment: Which Cypress version are you using?

Comment: I installed it via npm so it is the latest at current time: v3.2.0

Comment: Could you share a minimal GitHub repo with the problem please?

Comment: Try updating to Cypress 3.3.0, we've made a lot of improvements to network error handling in this release.

Comment: @ZachBloomquist Thank you very much, I will give a try

Comment: @Gearworks Did you find out what was the problem? I am having the same one.

Comment: same problem here with cypress 11.2. Why my app behave differently inside cypress?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Turns out I was unintentionally stubbing the response.

My code was:

```
cy.intercept('POST', '/route', {statusCode: 200}).as('someRoute'); <------WRONG
```

When it should be something like:

```
cy.intercept('/route').as('someRoute');
// code for clicking button/triggering the request
cy.wait('@someRoute').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Try editting the cypress.json file. Put the following line
"responseTimeout":{the time you want to wait}
By default this time is 30000 milliseconds.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it in my case.

I got null in ->

```
cy.wait(alias, options).then((xhr) => {
    const status = xhr.response.body.ok; // response was null
    expect(status).to.equal(true);
});
```

The reason for error in my case-
url contains another url.

I've intercepted the url "describe-something"
and then I intercepted the url "describe-something-something" which tried to intercept the first one and therefore its response was null.

The solution-
I just changed the url of the first request, instead of "describe-something" I used -> `new RegExp(/\/describe-something$/)`